# Connection Refused SSL Installation in Apache 2.4.7 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, apache2, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to install a SSL Certificate in my web server but after doing all the configuration steps I get a Connection Refused when I tried to enter to https://example.com .

If I go to the website with out the SSL in the port 80 it works fine.

My server it's in Amazon, I already update my security groups and allow HTTPS traffic inbound & outbound

```
    # iptables -L 
    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination         

    Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination         

    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination
```

My apache2.conf its :

```
    cat apache2.conf 
    # This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
    # configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
    # See for detailed information about
    # the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
    # hints.
    #
    #
    # Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
    # The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
    # upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
    # default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
    # virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
    # order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
    # possible.

    # It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
    # below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
    #
    #   /etc/apache2/
    #   |-- apache2.conf
    #   |   `--  ports.conf
    #   |-- mods-enabled
    #   |   |-- *.load
    #   |   `-- *.conf
    #   |-- conf-enabled
    #   |   `-- *.conf
    #   `-- sites-enabled
    #       `-- *.conf
    #
    #
    # * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
    #   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
    #   web server.
    #
    # * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
    #   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
    #   customized anytime.
    #
    # * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
    #   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
    #   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
    #   respectively.
    #
    #   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
    #   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
    #   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
    #   their respective man pages for detailed information.
    #
    # * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
    #   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
    #   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
    #   work with the default configuration.


    # Global configuration
    #

    #
    # ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
    # configuration, error, and log files are kept.
    #
    # NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
    # mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
    # at <URL:/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
    # you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
    #
    # Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
    #
    #ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

    #
    # The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
    #
    Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

    #
    # PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
    # identification number when it starts.
    # This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
    #
    PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

    #
    # Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
    #
    Timeout 300

    #
    # KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
    # one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
    #
    KeepAlive On

    #
    # MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
    # during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
    # We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
    #
    MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

    #
    # KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
    # same client on the same connection.
    #
    KeepAliveTimeout 5


    # These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
    User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
    Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

    #
    # HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
    # e.g.,  (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
    # The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
    # had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
    # each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
    # nameserver.
    #
    HostnameLookups Off

    # ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
    # If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
    # logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
    # container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
    #
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    #
    # LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
    # Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
    # "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
    #
    LogLevel warn

    # Include module configuration:
    IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
    IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

    # Include list of ports to listen on
    Include ports.conf


    # Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
    # not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
    # The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
    # the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
    # your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
    # access here, or in any related virtual host.
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
    </Directory>

    <Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options -Indexes +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    #<Directory /srv/>
    #   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    #   AllowOverride None
    #   Require all granted
    #</Directory>




    # AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
    # for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
    # directive.
    #
    AccessFileName .htaccess

    #
    # The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
    # viewed by Web clients.
    #
    <FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>


    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive.
    #
    # These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
    # (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
    # requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
    # requests.
    #
    # Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
    # Use mod_remoteip instead.
    #
    LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
    LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
    LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

    # Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
    # see README.Debian for details.

    # Include generic snippets of statements
    IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

    # Include the virtual host configurations:
    IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

My vhosts conf its:

```
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        LogLevel Debug
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/example/error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/example/acces.log common
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
        ServerName example.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.crt

    </VirtualHost>
```

I already do the a2enmod ssl

when i do a :
        service apache2 restart

My debug log sais :

```
    [Thu Feb 18 09:39:32.610644 2016] [ssl:info] [pid 3358] AH02200: Loading certificate & private key of SSL-aware server 'example.com:443'
    [Thu Feb 18 09:39:32.610888 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 3358] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(506): AH02249: unencrypted RSA private key - pass phrase not required
    [Thu Feb 18 09:39:32.610922 2016] [ssl:info] [pid 3358] AH01914: Configuring server example.com:443 for SSL protocol
    [Thu Feb 18 09:39:32.611239 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 3358] ssl_engine_init.c(791): AH01904: Configuring server certificate chain (3 CA certificates)
    [Thu Feb 18 09:39:32.611245 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 3358] ssl_engine_init.c(328): AH01893: Configuring TLS extension handling
    [Thu Feb 18 09:39:32.611249 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 3358] ssl_engine_init.c(838): AH02232: Configuring RSA server certificate
    [Thu Feb 18 09:39:32.611351 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 3358] ssl_util_ssl.c(407): AH02412: [example.com:443] Cert matches for name 'example.com' [subject: CN=example.com,OU=Domain Control Validated / issuer: CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=LINKGODADDY_REMOVED_BECAUSE_OF_STACKOVERFLOW,O=LINKGODADDY_REMOVED_BECAUSE_OF_STACKOVERFLOW\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US / serial: E02738D19782CD22 / notbefore: Feb 17 21:54:38 2016 GMT / notafter: Feb 17 21:54:38 2017 GMT]
    [Thu Feb 18 09:39:32.611360 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 3358] ssl_engine_init.c(893): AH02236: Configuring RSA server private key
    [Thu Feb 18 09:39:32.630680 2016] [ssl:info] [pid 3359] AH02200: Loading certificate & private key of SSL-aware server 'example.com:443'
    [Thu Feb 18 09:39:32.630882 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 3359] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(506): AH02249: unencrypted RSA private key - pass phrase not required
    [Thu Feb 18 09:39:32.630981 2016] [ssl:info] [pid 3359] AH01914: Configuring server example.com:443 for SSL protocol
    [Thu Feb 18 09:39:32.631308 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 3359] ssl_engine_init.c(791): AH01904: Configuring server certificate chain (3 CA certificates)
    [Thu Feb 18 09:39:32.631314 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 3359] ssl_engine_init.c(328): AH01893: Configuring TLS extension handling
    [Thu Feb 18 09:39:32.631319 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 3359] ssl_engine_init.c(838): AH02232: Configuring RSA server certificate
    [Thu Feb 18 09:39:32.631427 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 3359] ssl_util_ssl.c(407): AH02412: [example.com:443] Cert matches for name 'example.com' [subject: CN=example.com,OU=Domain Control Validated / issuer: CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=LINKGODADDY_REMOVED_BECAUSE,O=LINKGODADDY_REMOVED_BECAUSE_OF_STACKOVERFLOW\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US / serial: E02738D19782CD22 / notbefore: Feb 17 21:54:38 2016 GMT / notafter: Feb 17 21:54:38 2017 GMT]
    [Thu Feb 18 09:39:32.631434 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 3359] ssl_engine_init.c(893): AH02236: Configuring RSA server private key
```

First i thought that it was a firewall problem but i run a 
nc -lvp 443 in the server and then tried to connect me from another server when i have the apache stopped and i get a successful connection. If i try the same with the apache2 running :

```
    nc -lvp 443
    nc: Address already in use
```

I always follow the same steps to install the SSL certificate and its the first time that when i go to https://example.com always tell me Connection Refused.

Comment: Do you have a Listen directive for port 443 in ports.conf? Possibly related: https://serverfault.com/questions/525015/connection-refused-https-on-apache

Comment: I resolved the problem, i was setting up all in the server and i was behind a load balancer of amazon. So i install al the SSL Certificates in the ELB and it works! Thank you very much